# rosp_canopen canopen_motor_node fails to compile / needs code edit to compile

Tags: ros, ros-canopen

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

I want to `catkin_make` the recent version of `ros_canopen`, but this appears:

```
[100%] Building CXX object ros_canopen/canopen_motor_node/CMakeFiles/canopen_motor_node.dir/src/control_node.cpp.o
/home/marcel/ros/powerball_ws/src/ros_canopen/canopen_motor_node/src/control_node.cpp: In member function ‘virtual bool RobotLayer::canSwitch(const std::list<hardware_interface::ControllerInfo>&, const std::list<hardware_interface::ControllerInfo>&) const’:
/home/marcel/ros/powerball_ws/src/ros_canopen/canopen_motor_node/src/control_node.cpp:432:17: error: ‘canSwitch’ is not a member of ‘hardware_interface::RobotHW’
     (void) &hardware_interface::RobotHW::canSwitch; // compile-time check for recent ros-controls version of ros_control
             ^
make[2]: *** [ros_canopen/canopen_motor_node/CMakeFiles/canopen_motor_node.dir/src/control_node.cpp.o] Fehler 1
make[1]: *** [ros_canopen/canopen_motor_node/CMakeFiles/canopen_motor_node.dir/all] Fehler 2
make: *** [all] Fehler 2
Invoking "make -j4 -l4" failed
```

When removing line 432 -

```
(void) &hardware_interface::RobotHW::canSwitch; // compile-time check for recent ros-controls version of ros_control
```

from `control_node.cpp` it compiles and this seems not to affect the program at runtime. There is even this comment, suggesting, this is just a compile-time check.

Is this intended behaviour?

This seems to be intended behaviour. Although I could not see any difference while using ros_canopen package from when having to remove this one line of code to the situation where I did not.
`ros_canopen` 0.6.4 compiles fine when having `ros_control` version 0.9.3.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/214219/rosp_canopen-canopen_motor_node-fails-to-compile-/-needs-code-edit-to-compile/) by [Marcel Usai](https://answers.ros.org/users/17911/marcel-usai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 200 on 2015-07-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This behaviour is intended and should prevent you from chasing version incompatibilities for several hours.

`canopen_motor_node` features the switching between the different CANopen operation modes ([wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/canopen_motor_node#mode_switching)) at run-time.
For this to work a new interface was added to `ros_control` ([#200](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros_control/pull/200)) and finally got released with version 0.9.2/3.

This interface uses virtual methods and will therefore compile even if the base class does not have these methods.
Of cause it will not work as expected, since the device will never switch to the required mode.
In addition the new version of `canopen_402` will not forward commands if no mode was selected and stops all motion by setting the halt bit in the control word.

By the way, `ros_canopen` 0.6.4 and `ros_control` 0.9.3 are available from the ROS repo and do not have to be built from source.

---

Originally posted by [Mathias Lüdtke](https://answers.ros.org/users/4094/mathias-l%C3%BCdtke/) with karma: 1596 on 2015-07-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1